# Summarize values based on value in json array in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to summarize values in an array in a logic app based on another value in the same array. Can not find any good ways to do this as everything I've tried generates a lot of code....

The array I'm working with looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Employee": "1",
    "Amount": 50
  },
  {
    "Employee": "1",
    "Amount": 75
  },
  {
    "Employee": "3",
    "Amount": 80
  },
  {
    "Employee": "3",
    "Amount": 20.5
  },
  {
    "Employee": "2",
    "Amount": 50
  },
  {
    "Employee": "1",
    "Amount": 35
  },
  {
    "Employee": "1",
    "Amount": 40
  },
  {
    "Employee": "2",
    "Amount": 10
  },
  {
    "Employee": "2",
    "Amount": 2
  },
  {
    "Employee": "3",
    "Amount": 1
  }
]
```

And I would like to have it looking like this, where there are only one row for each Employee:

```
[
  {
    "Employee": "1",
    "Amount": 200
  },
  {
    "Employee": "3",
    "Amount": 101.5
  },
  {
    "Employee": "2",
    "Amount": 62
  }
]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: There's actually a connector coming that will do this for you ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au ... technically, you could use it now via HTTP requests but just know you'd be the first to use it.  If you're interested, sign up.  They'll be happy to assist you given you'd be the first.  It's the **Aggregate** operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connector in logic app that can provide the out of box solution for your requirement. You need to [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops) in through the array and perform the calculation as per your requirement but I will not suggest you leverage the loop, variables action as it may take time and cost you more.

The alternative would be leveraging the [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=consumption) (JavaScript code) to do the calculation as per your requirement. Please note that you will need Integration Account to run your inline code.

For complex calculation you can offload this functionality to azure function and write your code as per the [supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages) and call [azure function from logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption).

Comment: Not entirely true, the connector I mentioned does.  It's literally just been submitted to Microsoft.  Using the HTTP endpoints at this time will achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up using an Azure function to solve the problem, as we don't have access to an integration account in this project and I need to have this in production fairly quick.